# Check whether SMS available in unity3D (ios, android)

Tags: android, ios, mobile, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to find out a way in unity to check whether device supports SMS or not. I'm using `Etcetera` plugins for Android and IOS. It works like a charm in IOS but in Android, `EtceteraAndroid.isSMSComposerAvailable()`, it always gives 'false' even your device supports SMS. This is a bug in this plugin.

Is there any other way can I detect SMS in unity3D?

Answer (score 0):

Prime31 **EtceteraAndroid** uses `hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY)` to check if telephony feature exist on target device.

`PackageManager.FEATURE_TELEPHONY` works since Android API level 7(**Android OS 2.1**)

`hasSystemFeature` works since Android API level 5(**Android OS 2.0**)

Can you report your OS version on your target phone?